# Recursive unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang

I have a tree structure that internally uses unordered map

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>

struct Node {
        std::unordered_map<int, Node> children;
};

int main() {
        Node a;
}
```

It works just fine on Apple clang 11.0.3 and MSVC v19.24, but it fails to compile on clang 10.0.0 and gcc 10.1

While regular `std::map` works just fine on all compilers. I failed to find the reason for this discrepancy. Is there any way to use `std::unordered_map` as a value for itself? Or pointers is the only solution here?

Here's the compiler explorer link https://godbolt.org/z/6eYch9

Here's an error from gcc:

> ```
>     #3 with x86-64 gcc 10.1
>     In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/unordered_map:43,
>                     from <source>:1:
>     /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:
> In instantiation of 'struct std::pair<const int, Node>':
>     
>     /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/ext/aligned_buffer.h:91:28:
> required from 'struct __gnu_cxx::__aligned_buffer<std::pair<const int,
> Node> >'
>     
>     /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:233:43:
> required from 'struct
> std::__detail::_Hash_node_value_base<std::pair<const int, Node> >'
>     
>     /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:279:12:
> required from 'struct std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int,
> Node>, false>'
>     
>     /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1973:13:
> required from 'struct
> std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<std::allocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const
> int, Node>, false> > >'
>     
>     /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/hashtable.h:173:11:
> required from 'class std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<const int, Node>,
> std::allocator<std::pair<const int, Node> >,
> std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>,
> std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
> std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash,
> std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy,
> std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >'
>     
>     /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/unordered_map.h:105:18:
> required from 'class std::unordered_map<int, Node>'
>
>     <source>:4:39:   required from here
>     /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/stl_pair.h:218:11:
> error: 'std::pair<_T1, _T2>::second' has incomplete type
>
>       218 |       _T2 second;                ///< The second member
>           |           ^~~~~~
>     <source>:3:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct Node'
>         3 | struct Node {
>           |        ^~~~
>     Compiler returned: 1
> ```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

STL containers are not required to work with incomplete types. If you don't mind extra indirection, then the workaround is `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Node>>`

Comment: You could also use Boost.Container.

Answer (score 6):

It's the same problem as doing e.g.

```
struct Node
{
    Node child;  // An instance of the full structure
};
```

You can't use a structure (or class) before it's fully defined, which it is at the closing `}`.

You can however define *pointers* to the structure, because then the compiler don't need the full structure definition, only know the name of the structure:

```
struct Node
{
    Node* child;  // Pointer to the structure
};
```

So to solve your problem, you need a map of *pointers*:

```
std::unordered_map<int, Node*> children;
```

Comment: Since the node owns its children, that should be an `std::unique_ptr<Node>`, shouldn't it?

Comment: This does not explain discrepancy though

Comment: @Teivaz The other answer gets that too. Maybe due to how some of the maps happen to be implemented internally in some compilers/stdlibs, they can work with an incomplete type as template argument. But they don't need to, so you can't rely on whether they seem to now.

Answer (score 0):

Running into this while coding a Trie data structure I've noticed that in the latest of clang (v14) and GCC (v12) I don't get the error and my code operates as expected but anything below those versions (on godbolt.com) I get the same error. This is all using `-std=c++14` so it's should not be related to the standard.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).